GSC Core web vitals desktop data not available while mobile data is showing
GSC Core web vitals desktop data not available while mobile data is showing also most of the site traffic comes from the desktop site.
Also In Google Analytics realtime desktop data is coming from desktop.


I have tried fixing the page speed issue as well as the GSC errors

The eligibility criteria for CrUX is given here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/methodology
It could be you have less visitors on desktop than mobile, and not enough to cross the popularity thresholds (except figures of which are not given).
Or alternatively, that not enough desktop visitors use Chrome with a signed in profile, browser syncing, and usage statistics turned on.

As I shown in the screenshot I have sufficient desktop data as site is 8 month old

How does the screenshot show this? It shows over a 30 minute period you had 3 visitors some of whom were on desktop. There are many, many sites over 8 months old that don't get enough users to be listed in CrUX for either desktop or mobile (or both).

But it is showing data for mobile & mobile has less visitors on the site also site is enough   old to get all the traffic.

During that 30 minute period mobile had less visitors. CrUX is measured over 28-days so that may not be the case over that longer time frame. Also there are various other user criteria (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/methodology#user-eligibility). It could be the desktop users don't meet this criteria but the mobile ones do. The age of the site has nothing to do with this, as I said before: There are many, many sites over 8 months old that don't get enough users to be listed in CrUX for either desktop or mobile (or both)

Is there any solution to achieve this manually ?
